# make 0 to NA until first encounter of an integer in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in `R`.

I would like to convert `0` to `NA` **until** we first encounter an integer or number in each row.

Toy example:

```
a <- c(rep(0,5),rep(1,3))
b <- c(rep(0,4),rep(1,3),rep(0,1))
c <- c(rep(0,3),rep(2,3),rep(0,2))


df <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID = c("a","b","c"),rbind(a,b,c)))
df
```

here is the data frame:

```
   ID V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
   a  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
   b  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0
   c  0  0  0  2  2  2  0  0
```

In the example above for ID = "a" we encounter first integer/number in V7 so it should be NA until V6. For ID = "b" we encounter first integer at V6 so V2 thru V5 should be NA, similarly for ID = "c" we encounter first integer/number V5 so V2 thru V4 should be NA,

Here is the desired output:

```
   ID V2   V3   V4   V5   V6 V7 V8 V9
   a <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  1  1  1
   b <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    1  1  1  0
   c <NA> <NA> <NA>    2    2  2  0  0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can loop over the rows, `replace` the values to `NA` based on the cumulative sum

```
df[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) replace(x, cumsum(x)==0, NA)))
df
#  ID X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
#a  a NA NA NA NA NA  1  1  1
#b  b NA NA NA NA  1  1  1  0
#c  c NA NA NA  2  2  2  0  0
```

---

Another option is `rowCumsums` from `matrixStats` after converting the 'data.frame' to `matrix` for the selected columns

```
df[-1] <- replace(df[-1], rowCumsums(as.matrix(df[-1])) == 0, NA)
```

---

NOTE: `cbind` converts to a `matrix` and matrix can hold only a single class, so essentially, it converts the whole dataset to 'character' as 'ID' is 'character', then with `as.data.frame` (`stringsAsFactors = TRUE` by default, so it converts columns to `factor`).  It would be better `data.frame(...)` instead of `as.data.frame(cbind`

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("a","b","c"),rbind(a,b,c))
```

Answer (score 1):

additional option

```
library(tidiverse)
df <- data.frame(rbind(a,b,c))

df %>%
  t() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate_all(list(~if_else(cumany(. != 0), ., NULL))) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```